# What is the difference in creating objects in these two ways

Tags: java

what is the difference between creating an object like like

```
OverFlow a = new OverFlow();

OverFlow a;
```

Comment: Even though you seem to getting a lot of answers, I recommend you to read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Comment: Agreed. I was out of downvotes for research effort. A good beginner's book on Java, the Oracle tutorials, or just simply trying it would explain the difference.

Comment: This is a legit beginner question and should not have been down voted.

Comment: @SteveKuo - SO's purpose is not to replace a beginner's book on programming. This question shows no *research effort* which is the number one reason to downvote (hover your mouse over the down arrow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In second case, no object is created. The `a` variable remains uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
OverFlow a
```

bit has the same meaning in both cases: it creates a variable called `a` that stores a reference to an instance of class `OverFlow` (or a subclass).

In the first case, a new object is created and the reference is initialized to point to that object.

In the second case, the reference is not initialized and remains `null`.

Comment: Not to be pedantic but it's only `null` if it's a class field; in a method the compiler will puke at you that it hasn't been initialized.

Comment: @BrianRoach: Surely that's incorrect? I've just tested and `Object obj;` inside a method compiles just fine.

Comment: You'd get something similar to: `App.java:[26,6] variable foo might not have been initialized
1 error`

Comment: you didn't attempt to *use* it. The compiler ignores it in that case

Comment: So to be double pedantic - If you do that in a method, don't explicitly set it to `null`, then attempt to use the variable, it won't compile.

Comment: @BrianRoach: I am not sure I entirely agree, but I am going to leave it at that (don't think this debates adds a lot to the question at hand).

Answer (score 1):

```
OverFlow a;
```

equals

```
OverFlow a = null;
```

Comment: Only for fields (class variables). For local variables `OverFlow a` leave it unassigned.

Answer (score 0):

```
new OverFlow();
```

really creates an instance of class OverFlow, while

```
OverFlow a;
```

is just a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

In the first one, "a" has a value of a the newly constructed OverFlow object.

In the second one, it is null.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an object without defining it as a new Object, it will not be initialized (the constructor doesn't get called, either.). You should only use the second version to create objects within a try-catch-block.

Answer (score 0):

`OverFlow a;` does not create an object (i.e. an instance you can use). It only defines the variable `a` with the type `OverFlow` but it will be assigned to `null`. If you try to use it, you will therefore get a NullPointerException. Depending on your compiler, it will also most likely give you an 'uninitialized' variable warning.

`OverFlow a = new OverFlow();` does the same thing, except it makes an actual object (non-null) that is ready to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Basically,

```
OverFlow a;
```

tells the compiler, "There is eventually going to be a variable of type overflow, so get ready for it."

```
OverFlow a = new Overflow();
```

actually allocates the memory needed to store the variable and invokes the constructor for it